How to download a file from an S3 Bucket using ARN Credentials?
I have created my own S3 bucket handling class in C# using the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package, but I created it in a way which it uses an access- and secret key along with the region, etc. Now I also want to allow the use of credentials like ARN, host and access key alone.
Here is an example of the credentials I need it to work with:
ARN:         aws:s3:::Jet
Access key:  X0000X0XXX000XXX00X0
Host:        s3.company.holdings.co.za
Here is a download method of mine after my attempt at implementing both ways of connecting in which Advanced is the way that uses the secret key, etc and Basic is the way that uses the ARN, etc:
/// <summary>
/// Download a file from the S3 bucket.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file">The key of the file you want to download.</param>
/// <param name="downloadFolder">The path of the folder you want the file to be downloaded into.</param>
/// <returns>Bool indicating whether the operation was a success.</returns>
/// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
public bool DownloadFile(string file, string downloadFolder)
{
    bool result = true;
    try
    {
        try
        {
            switch (BucketType)
            {
                case S3BucketHandlerType.Advanced:
                    // THIS IS MY ORIGINAL CODE THAT WORKS USING Secret Key, etc
                    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(AccessKey, SecretKey, BucketRegion);
                    TransferUtilityDownloadRequest downloadRequest = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = this.BucketName,
                        Key = file,
                        FilePath = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, Path.GetFileName(file))
                    };
                    transferUtility.Download(downloadRequest);
                    transferUtility.Dispose();
                    break;
                case S3BucketHandlerType.Basic:
                    // THIS IS THE CODE I NEED WORKING WITH ARN, AccessKey & Host
                    AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, ARN);
                    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config
                    {
                        ServiceURL = Host,
                        AuthenticationRegion = BucketRegionCode,
                        ForcePathStyle = true
                    };
                    using (AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(creds, config))
                    {
                        TransferUtility transferUtilityB = new TransferUtility(client);
                        TransferUtilityDownloadRequest downloadRequestB = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = BucketName,
                            Key = file,
                            FilePath = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, Path.GetFileName(file))
                        };
                        transferUtilityB.Download(downloadRequestB);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            throw new AmazonS3Exception(ex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }
    return result;
}

What is the correct way of achieving this?
I have tried looking into other tickets/questions logged on forums but have been unsuccessful in finding on that matches what I want to accomplish. I simply want to know how to do operations with the S3 bucket using only the ARN, host and access key.

You can't. You need an Access Key (username) and Secret Key (password).
